# How to Install a windows Update based on the OS version in Windows 10

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I've two different windows updates which goes into to different versions of windows (for ex: 1703&1709), Now I would like to generate one single MSI, which goes onto both the systems and Install their respected updates based on the conditioning we keep.

I am unable to figure out a solution without writing a Custom Action, but this leads to issues. Does anyone has any idea how to approach this

Thank you

Comment: What kind of issues do you encounter with Custom Action?

Answer (score 0):

Add both updates to your install and configure their install based on the [OS properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/operating-system-property-values). Be aware that once you enter the installExecuteSequence only one MSI can run at a time so you'll need to either install in a bootstrapper or in the InstallUISequence.

Comment: Hi Dave,
OS Properties doesn't shoe any Properties for Win 10, So I've added a property to read Reg key of the OS ReleaseID(ex: 1703) and called this property in the condition which I had in my Installer file. But still doesn't work and it throws me 2755 error code with args 110

Comment: Just log an install on Win10 and check the log for the VersionNT, WindowsBuild, ServicePackLevel properties.